# Problem in creating an intent

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I am trying to initialize an intent in a class by :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this.LineView,gamematch.class);
```

but this is not accepted and it gives an error saying: " The constructor `Intent(LineView, Class<gamematch>)` is undefined " and gives a hint saying change to `Intent()`.

Is it the case that the class which extends different things can not be linked using Intents??

`LineView` extends `View` and `gamematch` extends `Activity` if that makes any difference in defining `Intent`s.
I have all the imports related to intent and have used intents within the same project but with two different classes (having same extends)

any help would be great :)

Comment: Follow Class Naming Conventions Too...: gamematch.class must be GameMatch.class

Comment: sure, I will take care of that from now :)

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of the constructor needs to extend Context, and is generally the currently active Context (i.e. the Activity that is currently active).

Answer (score 0):

try change

```
Intent i = new Intent(this.LineView,gamematch.class);
```

to

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,gamematch.class);
```

This constructor need a context and a class, not a view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,sorry for the typo in the question : I tried using Intent i = new Intent(this,gamematch.class); and  Intent i = new Intent(LineView.this,gamematch.class); both .   Both of them are not working.

Comment: Did you write it in a listenner, eg onClickListenner?
In this case, you should write:
Intent i = new Intent(<Activity>.this,gamematch.class);

with <Activity> is the name of the Activity that contain your LineView.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

Intent i = new Intent(LineView.this,gamematch.class);

Answer (score 0):

try something like this.

```
Intent SettingsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Application_Settings.class);
startActivity(SettingsIntent);
```